I just start learning C++, how to fix this?
So, i just recently install VS code and decided to learn C++, i follow a guide from the internet, however in the lsat step my terminal output seem kinda strange and i don't understand what it means, I only know that mine is different from what I was shown because they only have like 2 lines and mine showed 6, and also, the message i was trying to write show up 2 times (Like you can see, the " hello world" show up 2 times?). I don't know if this is a problem or not, but i want to fix it as soon as possible so it wouldn't get in my way in the future.
I have try unistall VS code, and reinstall it again but this problem still ahowed up. I don't know how to fix this, can anyone help me?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
